# HdrHistogram: how to control the number of buckets in outputPercentileDistribution()?

Tags: java, hdrhistogram

I've been using HdrPercentile library in Java to monitor distribution of certain number in my system.

I decided to take a shortcut and use outputPercentileDistribution to let HdrHistogram show me what it thinks of my data.

The output has been useful, but I have hard time understanding how HdrHistogram controls the number of buckets it prints.

The number is controlled by the function argument

> Produce textual representation of the value distribution of histogram
>   data by percentile. The distribution is output with exponentially
>   increasing resolution, with each exponentially decreasing
>   half-distance containing dumpTicksPerHalf percentile reporting tick
>   points.
>
> percentileTicksPerHalfDistance The number of reporting points per
>   exponentially decreasing half-distance

I do not understand exactly how it's translated into buckets. I did notice that the larger the number that I pass, the more buckets I get.

Can someone explain exactly how the buckets are set up?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code, I think I see what's going on there.

The function argument is slightly misnamed. It really should be `percentileBucketsPerHalfDistance`.

The system takes half the distance to 100% (initially 50%) and splits it into the  given number of buckets. So, for `percentileBucketsPerHalfDistance = 2` we get buckets at 0 and 25%.

Then the system takes a half of what' left to 100% again, let's say 50 to 75%, and splits it into the required number of buckets, let's say 50% and 62.5%.

Then we deal with 75% to 87.5%, split into 2 again, so we get 75% and 81.25%

Eventually we get so close to 100% that we overshoot and get 99.9997138977 and 100.0